# How to enable histogram in Auto mode on Fujifilm X-T20?

Tags: fujifilm, fujifilm-x-t20

How can I enable the histogram in Auto mode on a Fujifilm X-T20? It is useful for me because it helps me to adjust EV accordingly.

I find that I can customise the display to enable a histogram when the camera is not in Auto mode (signified by a yellow arrow in attached photo). However, I am unable to do the same when the camera is in Auto mode. At least I cannot figure out how to do it in the menu system.

(As part 2 of this question) I would like to have the lever appear in Auto mode as well.

[image: histogram on display]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Many features are disabled when Auto mode is enabled**, such as histogram and raw capture. Allowing certain settings to be customized would defeat the purpose of "Auto" mode, which is to maximize the number of decisions the camera makes for the user.

**FujiFilm X-Series cameras are modeless by default.** All settings can be changed or set to Auto, individually. This can be confusing for users who have come from other systems with separate Auto, Manual, Shutter Priority, and Aperture Priority modes.

To use "Shutter Priority", select a new shutter speed with the shutter speed dial. To use "Aperture Priority", turn on the aperture switch and rotate the ring (or thumb wheel). For full manual control, change both.

To make the camera automatically select all settings, similar to Auto mode, turn the all dials to "A" (aperture, shutter speed) or "AF" (focus). Also enable Zone focusing and face detection.