# How to change auto-focus point in Auto mode on Fujifilm X-T20?

Tags: autofocus, fujifilm

When I set my Fujifilm to AUTO mode, the focus points area seem to be only at the center of the screen.

[image]

Is there a way to make this to cover the whole area? So that if my subject is at the edges, it can also focus properly?

Comment: If you rotate the front dial to change from "AUTO SR+" to one of the specific automatic scene modes, does the restriction change?

Comment: It looks like it's decided to just use the faster hybrid phase-detect points rather than the wider array of contrast-detect points. It _may_ decide differently depending on the auto-scene recommendation.

Comment: [How to enable histogram in Auto mode on Fujifilm X-T20?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/103069/75526)

Comment: @mattdm no, it does not. If I want to make it cover the whole area, I need to set to manual and then the AF mode to Wide/Tracking.

Answer (score 1):

**Many features are disabled or cannot be changed when Auto mode is enabled.** In particular, the auto-focus mode and points cannot be changed in Auto mode. FujiFilm's Auto mode is *fully* automatic, which means the number of decisions the camera makes for the user is maximized. The more settings a user is allowed to customize, the less automatic it would be.

- FujiFilm's Auto mode is like using a self-driving car. If you don't like how the car drives and prefer to be a front-seat driver, don't use self-driving mode.

**FujiFilm X-Series cameras are modeless by default.** All settings can be changed or set to Auto, individually. This can be confusing for users who have come from other systems with separate Auto, Manual, Shutter Priority, and Aperture Priority modes.

To use "Shutter Priority", select a new shutter speed with the shutter speed dial. To use "Aperture Priority", turn on the aperture switch and rotate the ring (or thumb wheel). For full manual control, change both.

To make the camera automatically select all settings, similar to Auto mode, turn the all dials to "A" (aperture, shutter speed) or "AF" (focus). Also enable Zone focusing and face detection.

Comment: I would dispute the first point `Allowing certain settings to be customized would defeat the purpose of "Auto" mode`. making the AF area to cover the whole screen does not defeat the purpose of "Auto" mode, in contrast, it SHOULD BE how the "Auto" mode works. It will be impractical to ask someone else who takes my photo to put me in the center first and then recompose. Even in mobile phone camera, when you touch the edge of the screen, they also can focus there. I'd question why a mirrorless camera can't do this.

Comment: You can dispute it all you want, but that won't change how Auto mode works on FujiFilm X-series cameras. If you don't like how it is, you have to use the camera in the default modeless configuration.